# How do I evaluate Team Foundation Server locally?

Tags: tfs

I've been tasked with evaluating TFS 2010 for possible use in my group, but don't have access to a server at this point.  Is there a way to run it locally (Win XP) just to put it through it's paces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better if you download the VM for TFS 2012 by Brain Keller, you will be able to see most of the TFS features with hands-on labs.

[Visual Studio 2012 Application Lifecycle Management Virtual Machine and Hands-on-Labs / Demo Scripts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briankel/archive/2011/09/16/visual-studio-11-application-lifecycle-management-virtual-machine-and-hands-on-labs-demo-scripts.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I got it for 2010. Huge download, you will need Hyper-V (Windows 8 Pro and up or Server 2008 and newer) plus you might still end up having to configure it (mine did not have proper sharepoint integration, and reports were misconfigured as well). It comes with full (180 day limit) versions of Windows Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2, Sharepoint and TFS though. There also is a hosted solution, so that should be easiest at http://tfs.visualstudio.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

TFS2010 requires windows 2003, 2008, vista or 7, You can't install it directly on windows xp.  You could install it into a virtual machine running one of these operating systems, that would require a fair amount of ram.

However I get the feeling that you probably don't really have the hardware requirements to run TFS, and you probably don't really want to maintain a TFS server. You should probably look at using TFService instead (tfs.visualstudio.com) which is an online version of TFS2012, free for up to 5 users (however while it's in preview it's free for larger groups too).  You can install a patch so that VS2010 can access this service.